# SUM and UPDATE #temp skipping records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have this data a temp table #tbl with this order, Im trying to compute the difference between the first record with second, the second with third and so on, an update the result in field named Diff

The second problem to solve is I have to take only diff from CodeId 22 to 23, I have to discard the Diff between CodeId from 23 to next 22. I CodeId = 22 is GO, and 23 = Stop, I have to compute the driving time.

```
  Fecha               Driver   CodeId  Diff
  2014/03/01 14:00:00, 7168,     22  ,  0
  2014/03/01 14:30:00, 7168,     23  ,  0
  2014/03/01 14:40:00, 7168,     22  ,  0
  2014/03/01 16:10:00, 7168,     23  ,  0
  2014/03/01 16:50:00, 7168,     22  ,  0
  2014/03/01 17:20:00, 7168,     23  ,  0
  2014/03/01 18:30:00, 7168,     22  ,  0
  2014/03/01 19:10:00, 7168,     23  ,  0
```

I wrote this code but Im getting error:

```
    UPDATE #tbl
    SET Difer = DATEDIFF(second, Fecha, LEAD(Fecha,1, Fecha) OVER (ORDER BY Fecha))
    FROM #tbl

    Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
    Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.
```

Im using MS SQL server 2012

Dont know how to solve it, can u help me please. Thank you.

PD: I wrote this code while waiting for help

```
    ; WITH Sumar AS (
     Select Fecha as Fecha1, 
         DATEDIFF(second, Fecha, LEAD(Fecha,1, Fecha) OVER (ORDER BY Fecha)) as Total
     FROM #tbl)
    UPDATE #tbl
    SET Difer = Total
    FROM Sumar
    WHERE Fecha = Fecha1 AND EvenTypeId <> 23
```

and work fine for me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE_GO
AS(  
 SELECT Fecha , Driver, CodeId,Diff,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Fecha ASC) RN_Go
 FROM  #tbl
 WHERE CodeId = 22
 ),
 CTE_Stop
 AS
 (
 SELECT Fecha , Driver, CodeId,Diff,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Fecha ASC) RN_Go
 FROM  #tbl
 WHERE CodeId = 23
 )
UPDATE  S
SET S.Diff = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, G.Fecha, S.Fecha) 
FROM CTE_GO G INNER JOIN CTE_Stop S
ON G.RN_Go = S.RN_Go
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═════════════════════════╦════════╦════════╦══════╗
║          Fecha          ║ Driver ║ CodeId ║ Diff ║
╠═════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╬══════╣
║ 2014-03-01 14:00:00.000 ║   7168 ║     22 ║    0 ║
║ 2014-03-01 14:30:00.000 ║   7168 ║     23 ║   30 ║
║ 2014-03-01 14:40:00.000 ║   7168 ║     22 ║    0 ║
║ 2014-03-01 16:10:00.000 ║   7168 ║     23 ║   90 ║
║ 2014-03-01 16:50:00.000 ║   7168 ║     22 ║    0 ║
║ 2014-03-01 17:20:00.000 ║   7168 ║     23 ║   30 ║
║ 2014-03-01 18:30:00.000 ║   7168 ║     22 ║    0 ║
║ 2014-03-01 19:10:00.000 ║   7168 ║     23 ║   40 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩════════╩════════╩══════╝
```

Comment: Thank you for answer M.Ali, I was trying while waiting some help and wrote the following code and works. Thank you again